# sysmalloc assertion failed in c

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, malloc

I have use malloc() many time in my program. It works perfectly most of the time but for some inputdoes works, and  gdb prompt the following error:

**Error:**

```
 my_program: malloc.c:2394: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top==initial_top 
 (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse 
 (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize -  1)) == 0)' failed.
 Aborted
```

**The portion of code is:**

```
 uint8_t *hex_b;
 if((hex_b = malloc(len_b))==NULL)
 {
   fprintf(stderr," Malloc Failed\n");
 }
```

**But It works ,when i change the code as:**

```
uint8_t hex_b[len_b];
```

Comment: Provide a minimal complete example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: What is `len_b`?

Comment: @ThomasJager It is unimportant.

Comment: Some error occurred in the code prior to the `malloc`. Something like memory corruption or double-free.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow maybe `len_b` is important. I've seen implementations where `malloc(0)`  returns `NULL`

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt In this case the compiler issued an error for the declaration uint8_t hex_b[len_b];

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Ive haven't had an issue here: `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { char buf[argc-1]; printf("%p\n", buf); return(0);}.` The compiler can't always detect 0

Comment: Try running the program under [valgrind[(http://valgrind.org/). It usually does a stellar job pointing to the source of such memory corruption errors.